# Converting yyyy-mm-dd into Tuesday 25th

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a variable set with the format: `yyyy-mm-dd`, I want to convert this into the format of `Tuesday 25th` using JS (jQuery library.)

I've tried:

```
var now = new Date('2013-06-25').format("l jS");
```

Comment: This should help: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is more beauty than datejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, and as such does not do anything with dates. You'll either have to use another library, or write your own JavaScript.

Problem 2:

The Date() function/constructor doesn't recognize that format in some browsers, so you'll have to parse it on your own:

```
var s = '2013-06-25',
    y = +s.substr(0, 4),     // get the year
    m = +s.substr(5, 2) - 1, // get the month
    d = +s.substr(8, 2),     // get the date of the month
    date = new Date(y, m, d);
```

Problem 3:

There's no custom date formatting in JavaScript. Also, no way to get day names.

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
            'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var formatted = days[date.getDay()] + ' ' + d;
```

Problem 4:

No way to add 'th', 'nd', etc...

```
if (Math.floor(d % 100 / 10) === 1) { // add 'th' for the 11th, 12th, and 13th
  formatted += 'th';
}
else {
  formatted += {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}[d % 10] || 'th';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Moment js](http://momentjs.com/) is a great javascript library for dealing with js's date objects and includes flexible ways to format date objects.

This would give you the format you're looking for.

```
moment().format('dddd Do');
```

Note: The moment object is a wrapper to the native date object.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the jQuery dateFormat Plugin. There you have a lot of possibilities:

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat